# Express calling an api inside of a post request

Tags: node.js, express

I've hit a wall here, and can't really find a clear way of achieving this. I want to create a new video to add to my database. I get all the information from the view form, but a couple of the keys have to come from an api. So here's a basic example of what I have and need. What's a good way of achieving this?

```js
router.post("/new", function(req, res){
    var videoId = req.body.videoId;
    var views = req.body.views;

    //call the api with the video Id here somehow, and get title key for the video object below

    //"www.api.com/"+videoId"
    
    var video = {
        title: title, //title from received from the api call
        views: views
    }
    
    video.create(video, function(err, video){
        //etc
    })
});
```

Comment: send a get request to the api, and in the complete callback parse the body for said values, insert them into your video object, then continue. easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module built-in node to request the information from the API, otherwise [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), which is probably more convenient to use.

Your code would then look like:

```
var request = require('request')

router.post("/new", function(req, res){
    var videoId = req.body.videoId;
    var views = req.body.views;

    //call the api with the video Id here somehow, and get title key for the video object below
    request.get('www.api.com/' + videoId, function(err, res) {


        var videoData = {
            title: res.title, //title from received from the api call
            views: res.views
        }

        video.create(videoData, function(err, video){
            //etc
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Mehdi, thanks I guess that's what I was looking for. Looking at your answer, I can see I asked the wrong question. Basically I wanted to know how to send a request without using the router.get or app.get, since those require you to visit a certain directory before being called. I'm going with the npm request, which seems to be reccomended in other posts as well. Thank you!